# DirectX 11: Model not rendering from Model class

Tags: c++, draw, visual-studio-debugging, directx-11

Ok! Here goes. I've updated my code. However, after hours of debugging seemingly perfect code, I can't spot the problem. I've set up multiple breakpoints around the Vertex and Index buffer creation, and the class draw call.

I've created a temporary `vtest` struct for the purposes of testing. It carries the definition.

```
struct vtest{
    XMFLOAT3 Vertex;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};
```

Linked to a proper IA abstraction:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC InputElementDesc[] = {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },  
};
```

(All of which returns a `(HRESULT) S_OK`)

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDescription;
ZeroMemory(&BufferDescription, sizeof(BufferDescription));

BufferDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
BufferDescription.ByteWidth = sizeof(vtest) * sz_vBuffer;
BufferDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
BufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
BufferDescription.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA SRData;
ZeroMemory(&SRData, sizeof(SRData));
SRData.pSysMem = test;
SRData.SysMemPitch = 0;
SRData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

hr = Device->CreateBuffer(&BufferDescription, &SRData, &g_vBuffer);
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
ZeroMemory(&MappedResource, sizeof(MappedResource));
```

The `vtest` struct fills proper, and:

```
DeviceContext->Map(g_vBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &MappedResource);
```

Succeeds, also with `(HRESULT) S_OK`.

Indices initialized as such:(One-dimensional `DWORD` array of indices.)

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC iBufferDescription;
ZeroMemory(&iBufferDescription, sizeof(iBufferDescription));

iBufferDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
iBufferDescription.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD)*sz_iBuffer;
iBufferDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
iBufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags = NULL;
iBufferDescription.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iSRData;
iSRData.pSysMem = Indices;

hr = direct3D.Device->CreateBuffer(&iBufferDescription, &iSRData, &g_iBuffer);
```

The IA `Set...` calls are in the `draw()` call:

```
DeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_vBuffer, &stride, &Offset);
DeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_iBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
```

Other settings: (Edit: Corrected values to show configuration.)

```
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC DrawStyleState;
DrawStyleState.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
DrawStyleState.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
DrawStyleState.DepthBias = 0;
DrawStyleState.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
DrawStyleState.DepthClipEnable = false;
DrawStyleState.MultisampleEnable = true;
DrawStyleState.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
DrawStyleState.ScissorEnable = false;
```

My Depth Stencil code.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC DepthStenDescription;
ZeroMemory(&DepthStenDescription, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));

DepthStenDescription.Width = cWidth;
DepthStenDescription.Height = cHeight;
DepthStenDescription.MipLevels = 0;
DepthStenDescription.ArraySize = 1;
DepthStenDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
DepthStenDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
DepthStenDescription.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
DepthStenDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
DepthStenDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
DepthStenDescription.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
DepthStenDescription.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC DSVDesc;
ZeroMemory(&DSVDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
DSVDesc.Format = DSVDesc.Format;
DSVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
DSVDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
```

And finally, my entity class `draw()` method:

```
void    Entity::Draw(){
    UINT stride = sizeof(vtest);
    UINT Offset = 0;

    ObjectSpace = XMMatrixIdentity();
    m_Scale = Scale();
    m_Rotation = Rotate();
    m_Translate = Translate();

    ObjectSpace = m_Scale*m_Rotation*m_Translate;
    mWVP = ObjectSpace*direct3D.mView*direct3D.mProjection;

    LocalWorld.mWorldVP = XMMatrixTranspose(wWVP);

    DeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(direct3D.MatrixBuffer, 0, NULL, &LocalWorld, 0, 0);
    DeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &direct3D.MatrixBuffer);

    DeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_vBuffer, &stride, &Offset);
    DeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_iBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    DeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    DeviceContext->DrawIndexed(e_Asset.sz_Index, 0, 0);
}
```

The code compiles, and the backbuffer presents correctly, but no model. 
[image: Blank buffer]

Initialization of DirectX functions seem to be fine too...[image: DirectX Debugger]

*Update* From Banex's suggestion, using the Visual Studio DirectX Debugging tools yield that I may have gone wrong in my `.hlsl` file. [image: Vertex Black Hole Shader of Division by Zero.]

I think also I may have gone wrong at shader initialization, since my shader really is simple, and really works as a vert/pix pass-through file:

Comment: You can try debugging the program with the Visual Studio Graphics Debugger to analyse what is going on at each stage of the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! I can dig a bit deeper... What a robust set of DirectX debugging tools! (Just appeared, hehe)Going through a small cramming session on debugging functionality - will post/update.

Comment: Looks like I need to update (Windows) to get full (vslog) functionality, but I found some resources to dig into. Will update post a bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the `.hlsl` file and doing further debugging; setting `output.position = position;` rather than being multiplied by the world matrix, the model was drawn on screen, implying a bad matrix calculation causing an extreme warp, or null values, stored in the constant buffer.

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer:register(b0)
{
    float4x4 WVP;
}

struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;
    output.position = position;// mul(position, WVP);
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}


float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```